# Glide does not showing images from backendless URL

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading, backendless

I'm working on android and using 'backendless' as mbass. I have uploaded a picture in their file storage and I'm given a public URL for image retrieving. I'm retrieving image successfully by simple 'HttpURLConnection' but when I use glide, it always stuck in 'error' instead of retrieving the image. and glide works on other URL's which I copied from Google and it works fine. but I gave backendless URL it doesn't work.

```
Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load("https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage.png")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_video_call_white_36dp)
                    .error(R.drawable.loginbackground)
                    .into(ImageView);
```

and glide version is: 3.7.0

here is my backendless URL: https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage.png

Comment: I tried it on my side and it seems to work fine for me with Glide. It is taking some seconds but it works. Check once again.

Comment: `.load("https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage")`. Didn't you forget a `.png` there?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I added it but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the image in my device using Glide. Please find the attached image.

(version: compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1')

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage.png")
            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.placeholder_gray)))
            .error(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.placeholder_gray)))
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I'm working in fragment, doest that effect? plus here is my code, `Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load("https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage")
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_video_call_white_36dp)
                        .error(R.drawable.loginbackground)
                        .into(ImageView);`

Comment: this is my glide version, compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: It is showing an error, it shows the 'error' image.

Comment: It is working now, I didn't change a single word, tried it again and it worked. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of the support of Https.

gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
```

HttpsUtils

```
public class HttpsUtils{
public static SSLSocketFactory getSslSocketFactory(InputStream[] certificates, InputStream bksFile, String password){
    try{
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = prepareTrustManager(certificates);
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = prepareKeyManager(bksFile, password);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager trustManager = null;
        if (trustManagers != null){
            trustManager = new MyTrustManager(chooseTrustManager(trustManagers));
        } else{
            trustManager = new UnSafeTrustManager();
        }
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, new SecureRandom());
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    } catch (KeyManagementException e){
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e){
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

private class UnSafeHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier{
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){
        return true;
    }
}

private static class UnSafeTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)throws CertificateException{}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)throws CertificateException{}

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){
        return new X509Certificate[]{};
    }
}

private static TrustManager[] prepareTrustManager(InputStream... certificates){
    if (certificates == null || certificates.length <= 0) return null;
    try{
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null);
        int index = 0;
        for (InputStream certificate : certificates){
            String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificate));
            try{
                if (certificate != null)
                    certificate.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
            }
        }
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        return trustManagers;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

private static KeyManager[] prepareKeyManager(InputStream bksFile, String password){
    try{
        if (bksFile == null || password == null) return null;
        KeyStore clientKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        clientKeyStore.load(bksFile, password.toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(clientKeyStore, password.toCharArray());
        return keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CertificateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static X509TrustManager chooseTrustManager(TrustManager[] trustManagers){
    for (TrustManager trustManager : trustManagers){
        if (trustManager instanceof X509TrustManager){
            return (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static class MyTrustManager implements X509TrustManager{
    private X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager;
    private X509TrustManager localTrustManager;

    public MyTrustManager(X509TrustManager localTrustManager) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException{
        TrustManagerFactory var4 = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        var4.init((KeyStore) null);
        defaultTrustManager = chooseTrustManager(var4.getTrustManagers());
        this.localTrustManager = localTrustManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException{}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException{
        try{
            defaultTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        } catch (CertificateException ce){
            localTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

}

RetrofitUtils

```
public class RetrofitUtils {
public static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient(InputStream... certificates)
{
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = HttpsUtils.getSslSocketFactory(certificates, null, null);
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
    builder = builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return builder.build();
}
```

}
Application

```
Glide.get(this).register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(RetrofitUtils.getOkHttpClient()));
```

Finally

```
        Glide.with(this).load("https://api.backendless.com/CF512434-CCA8-067C-FF92-D76481A44000/v1/files/profilePhotos/mubtada.syedprofileImage.png").centerCrop().into(iv_icon);
```